# Frequency range of AnaylserNode.getFloatFrequencyData()/getByteFrequencyData()

Tags: web-audio-api

For the AnalyserNode in the Web Audio API, what is the frequency range of the data returned by [getFloatFrequencyData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getFloatFrequencyData) and [getByteFrequencyData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteFrequencyData)?  Can I assume the AnalyserNode is simply FFT, making the range zero-to-half-the-sample-rate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.  The frequency bins are linearly spread across the frequencies from 0 to 1/2 the sample rate.